# Entering data in a cell and pressing enter activates a button on my form

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button with the `Button_Click` event macro with the following code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'
' Button1_Click Macro

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(RAND()*25+1)"        
End Sub
```

If I enter data into any cell in the spreadsheet, once I press enter the button activates.  I think it is reading my left mouse **click** directly and not as a press onto the button.

Comment: You should provide some more details, the error seems very strange to reproduce.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, can you try to check your worksheet if you don't have `Worksheet_Change event`?

Comment: I know it shouldn't be the case, took Excel a few years back in College, never had the problem.  checking now

Comment: Haven't found it.  Nothing in any of my click codes, possibly in teh settings?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using the Random function , so if you change or alter any cell in worksheet it will change . So it is nothing to do with mouse click as far i guess and enter is event in excel which tends to change the data , in your case is random function Formula applied to particular excel cell it will change as other cells value are altered or changed .
So for your Purpose Use below code ::

```
Sub 

  Button1_Click()
  Sheet2.Activate
  Sheet2.Select

  Range ("B1") = Rnd()*(25+1)

End Sub
```

Reply !!!!

Thanks